# Xamarin.Forms - Fire Event before App closes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Its possible to fire an event before the app closes? For exemple in my App i want so send a request to my api when the App closes to change the user state to offline.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect app closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913175/detect-app-closing)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xamarin you have one override method in App.xaml.cs called onsleep you can put your code there but it will trigger when your app goes in background also.

Comment: I see, i just wanted to execute my code just when the app closes but for now i think it does the job, thanks!