# How to know if chat between 2 users is active in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat feature in my app where I am sending push notification to users but I've come across a problem as I don't want to send the push if 2 users are already chatting with each other. How can I know if the chat is active between the 2 users? And how to know if someone has closed the chat session?

Would really appreciate the help.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay so here the deal.**

Let suppose there are two Users, A & B.
User A has entered the Chat screen, at the same time a `[Map:bool]` will be send to the firestore that `"IsActive_A: true"`. *(This is for User A, Use similar field for UserB).*

and when the User A leaves the Chat, Or click the back button or `onDispose` method is called. the same function of sending `[Map:bool]` will be send to there firestream with value equal to `false`.

**This is all i can give you right now, if you want further explaination please share some related code!**

Comment: Hi Sayed, thanks for the reply but what if user closes the app directly without closing the chat? How do you handle that situation?

Comment: You can disable the status  in `App.OnSleep` , the method could be triggered when app is closed , check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47913258/8187800.

Comment: Thanks @ColeX-MSFT. It has helped me resolve that issue as well. Cheers!